# automate software/page feature/notepad++ feature?

Tags: notepad++, document-automation

I'm wondering if there's something I can use to make something easier, it's easier if I explaint through an example.

I'm working on a stats change in RPG Maker, and for this feature to work I need to be able to change a line 10000 times over and I don't really wanna sit here the rest of my life editing all of those lines, anyway here's an example:

1(Level),10000(Health),10000(Mana),1000(Attack),1000(Defense),1000(Magic),1000(Magic Defense),1000(Agility),1000(Luck)
this is the line I need to increment 10000 times over so that the line ends up looking like

1,10000,10000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000

2,10100,10100,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010

3,10200,10200,1020,1020,1020,1020,1020,1020

and so on till it looks like:

10000,100000,100000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000

So yeah, sitting here forever editing each line like that isn't really doable, might be okay for maybe 100 lines, but I'm gonna work with 10000 rows so yeah.

Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

-FrozdY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily in Excel.

Create the below table:

[image: First table]

Highlight both rows:

[image: Highlight both rows]

Grab the corner handle and drag down:

[image: Drag to increment]

The little `10` in that box represents the value in the first column, which looks like your level number. Keep going until you reach whatever level you want to stop at.

Once done, save it as a CSV files and you'll have exactly what you need.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I don't own Excel :( is there any other solution you know of? I don't really wanna download fake programs.

Comment: You can probably achieve the same thing in [Libre](http://www.libreoffice.org/) or [Open](http://www.openoffice.org/) Office, both of which are free. If you don't want to download anything you should be able to also do this with [Google Sheets](http://sheets.google.com), which is online and free to use.

Comment: @FrozdY Or you can copy the end result directly out of here: http://pastebin.com/ths7iSEH

Comment: It'd be good if you could mark this as answered. The method I proposed is the exact same as I used to generate that file.

Comment: I'm new to this site Michael, how do I close it?

Comment: @frozdy just check the green tick beside my answer. Hit the up arrow as well.

Comment: I need 15 rep for the up arrow, I already tried it, I only have 11 :(

Comment: No worries. You'll get there eventually.

Comment: I got 13 now, so as soon as I get 15, I'll do the arrow :D